# using pouchdb along with nativescript

Tags: telerik, pouchdb, nativescript

Is there any example of using pouch-db along with native-script ? I want to give offline support to my app. I didn't find any example of both pouch-db along with native-script.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not supported [tweet](https://twitter.com/nolanlawson/status/677884973135728641) but if you want something similar you can always use [couchbase](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/nativescript-couchbase) and if that still does not satisfy your needs feel free to search [nativescript rocks a community resources site](http://nativescript.rocks/all.php) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=nativescript)